# Files upload in Spring using PUT method - testing and general idea

Tags: java, spring, rest, file-upload, groovy

I am designing REST API of simple file storage where one of the operations is file upload that goes together with some file metadata (using "multipart/form-data").
For some cases I need the file ID to be generated out of my application so I use PUT Http method.  When ID goes from outside the best practice is to use PUT method instead of POST. The reason is that PUT operation is idempotent. POST is not idempotent and is used when ID is generated internally.

Do you think that going with PUT is correct for file upload? (I have also POST because ID is sometimes generated internally)

Assuming that it is correct I have an issue with automated integration testing in Spring. The problem is with MockMvc support class called MockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder when writing integration test. It does not allow to change POST to PUT. Http method is constructor parameter somewhere higher in inheritence hierarchy and the filed is "private final". All the constructors of these classes are with default visibility modifier so when I extend it I am not able to call super constructors. It is completly sealed.

Any idea how to achieve this call with PUT method? (I can use Java or Groovy for this)

```
ResultActions response= mockMvc.perform(
        fileUpload("/files")
                .file(file)
                .param("origin", origin)
)
```

Comment: PUT is an appropriate choice for a file upload if the basic idea is that the file is available at the URI where you PUT it -- `PUT /a/b/c.json` is a good choice if `GET /a/b/c.json` is supposed to return the contents of the file.  See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.4

Comment: Exactly, this is my case.